# Multiple devices with same IP address

Tags: ip-address, vlan

Is it possible that one computer talks to several devices with the same IP address. I would like to realize this with the following setup:

1. one GNU/Linux box with several virtual interfaces, each is assigned a different IP address and VLAN
2. switch where every port is in different VLAN, except port that is connected to the computer (if I remember correctly that is called a trunk port?)
3. somehow configure my application (e.g. ping) to use the interface I want

Is my way of thinking in the right direction? Did I miss something or write totally incorrect/impossible stuff?

I cannot change the IP addresses of the devices that my computer connects to (they come from the store with this IP address and I have to configure them)

Comment: Why cant you configure each device with a different IP?

Comment: Because they come preconfigured with the same IP address, and I have to configure them (IP address and some other things). So I want to make process faster for me.

Comment: I think your only option is to configure each device one by one.

Comment: It's 2012. What kind of backwards devices don't do IPv4 link-local (or IPv6 link-local) by now?

Comment: Good point, I will check if the devices support autoIP, hadn't thought of that one.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that one computer talks to several devices with the same IP address.

No.

One way I can think of is to have one NAT router for each device. Then your computer talks to different IP-addresses, the NAT routers allow the traffic to reach devices with a common IP-address.

Comment: But would not VLANs separate the network on layer 2, so I do not hved problem with routing?

Comment: @v_m: The difficulty is that IP intend you to use IP-addresses (not interfaces) to address other devices. I don't know how to force a specific instance of an application to use only a specific "virtual interface". Choice of network interface for outbound data *is* a routing question - usually handled centrally by the O/S.

Answer (score 0):

"Is it possible that one computer talks to several devices with the same IP address"

Yes, it's called a multicast address. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address. Try pinging 224.0.0.1. If you are on a corporate network, chances are that multicast address is filtered. However, at home (for instance) you should receive a response from multiple devices.

Regarding the comment on link-local addresses: it would not be a good idea for your device to only be configured with a link-local address. They will not be able to talk to computers on the rest of the Internet. That is, they can only talk to things behind your router. A link-local address is a last ditch effort to establish basic communication.

I have a feeling you may know this already, but for future reference I feel it is worth making some clarification.